# How to check the if statement value in drools using dialect "Mvel"?

Tags: java, json, drools, rule-engine, mvel

I have a json below

```
"root":[
  {
    "refDataId": 1,
    "children": [
      {
        "refDataId": 20
      },
      {
        "refDataId": 99,
        "otherValue": "Facility"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "refDataId": 2,
    "children": [
      {
        "refDataId": 30
      },
      {
        "refDataId": 99,
        "otherValue": "Officer"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How to check the value above using the if statement *in rule drools*?

*I edited the question. This is for drools rule*

*For example my rules is:*

```
rule "test"
    when
        RuleEngine(inputObject!.adultHealth!.children contains 99)
    then
        info("children contains value 99");
end
```

And how to check the value of `"refDataId": 99,` and `"otherValue": "Officer"`?

If the value has to get from 2nd child json `"refDataId": 2,`

Comment: What did you try so far? I can't see any if-statement so please share your code and what problems you're facing exactly. Besides that please take a [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You can extract data using any json parser 
I have used [org.json](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20160810)

The following code tries to find an OFFICER from your json data.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);

    JSONArray objArray = obj.optJSONArray("root");

    for (Object jo : objArray) {
        JSONObject arrayElement = new JSONObject(jo.toString());
        JSONArray childrenArray = arrayElement.getJSONArray("children");

        for (Object child : childrenArray) {

            JSONObject childJo = new JSONObject(child.toString());

            if (Integer.parseInt(childJo.get("refDataId").toString()) == 99) {
                if (childJo.get("otherValue").toString().equals("Officer")) {
                    System.out.println("Success Officer Found !");
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking here [Nested JSON iterations using drools Fluent API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46014752/nested-json-iterations-using-drools-fluent-api) it seems to me it is enough to create data objects corresponding to structure of your JSON.